# How do I read/add event in another persons google calendar using the google API?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am creating an app, something like a reservation room manager in Java EE. I would like to have a calendar for each room.

How can I access more google calendars (each room) without any user consent, with permissions to create and read events from these calendars?

I tried to write something, but I only can access my own calendar with user consent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google api's, like Facebook, LinkedIn... Use the oauth2 to authorize other applications to use credential of client. You have, for the first time,to get the token from google api, and to get it you should give an interface to user to validate the authorization and get the token from google.